# Foursquare OAuth2 401 error

Tags: php, curl, oauth, oauth-2.0, foursquare

Using PHP and curl to generate an access token with this url:

`https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_SECRET&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri='.urlencode('MY_REDIRECT_URL').'&code='.$token['oauth_token']`

This processes just fine and returns a token. This token only changes when I reset the consumer key and secret at foursquare.com

Using that token with

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/search?name=test&oauth_token=RETURNED_TOKEN

always returns a 401 error. I used these instructions https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth

Comment: You have your access token, pretty hard to figure out with you got the 401 unauthorized. Check http headers maybe you will find other information.

Comment: Please do check this to deduce your 401 http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#http_codes

Comment: ok I just tested the users/search url in my browser outside the script and it worked. I'm reviewing my php script and will post the error soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here's what was going on:

in the oauth-php client code, the getQueryString method of the OAuthRequestSigner had the following condition when building the request url query string to prevent adding OAuth 1.0 signed params:

```
 (strncmp($name, 'oauth_', 6) != 0
```

I have a config file to manage my OAuth parameters and added

```
 $param=array(
   ...
   'oauth2'=>true
   ...);
```

which is passed to the OAuthRequestSigner class and adjusted the condition to

```
 ( (strncmp($name, 'oauth_', 6) != 0 || $param['oauth2'] )
```